# Prove $SPAN(S)$is the smallest subspace of $V$ that contains the vectors $v_1,...,v_p$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $V$ be a vector space and $S=${$v_1,...,v_p$} be a set in in $V$. Prove $SPAN(S)$is the smallest subspace of $V$ that contains the vectors $v_1,...,v_p$.

Proof: let $B=${$v_1,...,v_n$} with $n≤p$ be a subset of $S$ and also a basis for $SPAN(S)$, then $SPAN(S)=SPAN(B)$. Now, assume that there is a smaller basis {$v_1,...,v_{n-1}$} s.t. $SPAN(v_1,...,v_{n-1})=SPAN(B)$. Because $B$ is linearaly independent $v_n$ is not a linear combination of {$v_1,...,v_{n-1}$}, so $v_n∉SPAN(v_1,...,v_{n-1})=SPAN(B)$, but this is a contradiction as $v_n∈SPAN(B)=SPAN(S)$. Therefore $SPAN(S)$is the smallest subspace of $V$ that contains the vectors $v_1,...,v_p$.

Please comment and provide feedback on the validity of my proof. Thank you.

Comment: How d you define the span of a subset of a vector space?

Comment: Did I make some error?

Comment: How does that answer my question? There are two standard ways of defining the span of a subset of a vector space and I can't comment on your attempted proof without knowing which one you are using.

Comment: okay sorry.  define the span of a subset of a vector space like this. let $S=${$v_1...v_n$} be a subset of a vector space $V$. then $SPAN(S)=c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n$ where $c_1...c_n$  are some scalar real numbers. does that answer your question?

Comment: How do you define a subspace to be smaller than another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof assumes that, given a set $S=\{v_1,\ldots,v_p\}$, then there is a $n\leqslant p$ such that $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $\operatorname{span}(S)$. That is not true. For instance, if $v_1=0$ and $v_2\ne0$, then there is no such $n$.

You can do it as follows. Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$ such that $W\supset S$. Then, since $W\supset S$ and since $W$ is a vector space, $W$ contains all linear combinations of elements of $S$. In other words, $W\supset\operatorname{span}(S)$. This proves that $\operatorname{span}(S)$ is contained in every subspace of $V$ containing $S$. Therefore, since $\operatorname{span}(S)$ is a subspace containing $S$, it is the smallest such subspace.

Comment: but in that case cant we just skip $v_1=0$  and not include in the basis. I didn't say anything about retaining the order in my subset. does that change anything?

Comment: If you write that $B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ with $n\leqslant p$, then you are saying that $B$ consists of the first $n$ elements of $S$. For instance, if $p=3$ and $n=2$, $S=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ and $B=\{v_1,v_2\}$.

Comment: Anyway, there's a big jump when you say that therefore $\operatorname{span}(S)$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ that contains $S$.